# Auto-removing all newlines from Haml output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Haml in a Rails 3 app, and its newlines drive me nuts!  For example,

```
%span
  foo
```

renders as

```
<span>
foo
</span>
```

But I'd much rather want

```
<span>foo</foo>
```

The reason (apart from being cleaner XML) is that extra newlines are a problem for my Selenium tests because they mess up the ability to do XPath queries like `"//span[.='foo']"`.  So I'd have to write `'\nfoo\n'` instead (ew!), or use `//span[contains(text(), 'foo')]`, which matches too broadly.

I know I could use the alligator operators ("<" and ">") to strip whitespace, but since I don't ever have a case where I *want* the newlines to appear in the output, I'd just end up adding them mechanically at the end of each line.  And that just seems very unDRY.

So now I see two solutions:

1. Force Haml to never emit newlines unless they come from a Ruby expression.  I see some `nuke_inner_whitespace` / `nuke_outer_whitespace` variables spread around the Haml code that might do the job, but I'm not sure how to change them without resorting to gratuitous monkey-patching.
2. Hook into Rails to apply a `gsub!("\n", "")` to all rendered HTML.  (For textarea's and pre's, I could still use `~ "foo\nbar"` to make Haml emit `foo&#x000A;bar`.)  But where's the right place to hook into Rails?  I'm a little lost in the code.

Any pointers or other suggestions appreciated!

**Update:** I've used Jason's monkey patch below for a while now and I'm beginning to think that it's not worth it.  E.g. if I want to get `<span>[del]</span> <span>foo</span>`, it's difficult to *not* have the blank space in between nuked.  Even the following will render as `[del]foo` on the page:

```
%span
  = '[del] '
%span
  foo
```

So I think I'm going back to adding alligator operators manually (see my self-answer down below).  Live and learn.

Thanks again to Jason! :)

Comment: If there were a few cases you wanted to keep whitespace, you could negate the booleans instead of forcing them to true in the monkey patch. Generally I think it's better to learn to love the default whitespace :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you place a less-than sign at the end of the element name the whitespace around the content will be suppressed:

```
%span<
  foo
```

See [whitespace removal](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_) in the Haml reference for more details.

There doesn't appear to be any clean way to force these flags on for all tags but the following monkey patch works fine with Haml 3.0.24:

```
module Haml::Precompiler
  def parse_tag_with_nuked_whitespace(line)
    result = parse_tag_without_nuked_whitespace line
    unless result.size == 9 && [false,true].include?(result[4]) && [false,true].include?(result[5])
      raise "Unexpected parse_tag output: #{result.inspect}"
    end
    result[4] = true # nuke_outer_whitespace
    result[5] = true # nuke_inner_whitespace
    result
  end
  alias_method_chain :parse_tag, :nuked_whitespace
end
```

It probably wouldn't be hard to fork Haml and add an option to the Engine options to always nuke whitespace. The parse_tag method could check this option if enabled and set the inner and outer flags to true. I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: Not to sound ungrateful, but I actually wrote "I know I could use the alligator operators ("<" and ">") to strip whitespace" ... ;-)  I wouldn't ask a question without consulting the reference, for what it's worth.

Comment: Sorry. I completely missed that bit.

Comment: Jo: I have added a monkey patch to do what you're after. Not seeing a cleaner way.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool -- thanks!  Sticking this in config/initializers/haml_nuke_whitespace.rb works great for me.  And as monkey patches go, this is surprisingly pretty.  I'll remember the alias_method_chain method.  Also, forking HAML to add a proper option has been duly added to my things-to-do-some-day list. :)

Comment: An update on this: I used this for a bit, but auto-stripping all whitespace turns out to cause way too much pain to be worth it in practice. I'm now explicitly adding "<" and ">" in the places where I need it stripped. Still, thanks for your great answer, Jason!

Comment: what about your SEO meta ? (meaning cleaning up haml tags attributes)

Comment: Old link for whitespace removal doesn't work anymore
New link:
https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace-removal--and-

Answer (score 2):

A few ways to do it:

```
%span foo

%span= "foo"

- foo = ["f", "o", "o"].join("")
%span= foo

%span #{"foo"}

- foo = ["f", "o", "o"].join("")
%span #{foo}
```

Comment: Huh, good point.  Though many times, instead of a single "foo" expression, I have plenty of HAML code inside the element.  So pulling it up into the same line as the %element doesn't work as a general solution, I think.

Comment: Use the Haml multiline syntax so that you can spread your code across multiple lines but have Haml treat it as one line.

Comment: Actually, I believe the multiline operator will only span Ruby code, not nested HAML code.  http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#multiline

Comment: The multiline operator will span text as well, including nested HAML. Try it out. Note that this will include in the output all the whitespace preceding each pipe character except the last.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what you mean.
"%p       |\n
␣␣%span  |\n
␣␣␣␣text |"
will result in
<p>%span    text</p>

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @yfeldblum's answer, I decided to simply split on newlines and join on spaces, in order to avoid newlines in html rendered into js. For example:

```
- content = capture_haml do
  %div
    %ul
      %li Stuff
# ...
```

and then later,

```
:javascript
  var stuff = "#{content.split("\n").join(" ")}";
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I'll try to self-answer my question -- there's probably no clean/sensible way to remove all newlines, but perhaps I don't actually need that.  For typical XPath test expressions to work nicely, it's enough if *inline* elements don't have newlines around them.

So I guess I'll just put an inner-whitespace-eater ("<") after any tag that contains inline elements (p, li, span, a, etc.).  This seems to be working reasonably well so far.  E.g.

```
%div
  %ul
    %li<
      %span<
        stuff...
```

And all the other (i.e. most) newlines can stay and won't do any harm.

Sorry everyone for the messy question!