# Remove whitespace in Haml with a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

This question is similar to this one, but with an extra wrinkle:

[Auto-removing all newlines from Haml output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320138/auto-removing-all-newlines-from-haml-output)

Suppose you're constructing a comma-separated list of links with code like this:

```
- foos.each_with_index do |foo, i|
  = ', ' if i > 0
  = link_to foo.name, foo
```

How do you do that without getting whitespace in front of the comma? I don't see any way to do this with the existing alligator operators or `surround`/`precede`/`succeed`.

Is there some way to rewrite the loop so you can use these operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since link_to is just a helper that returns a string, you can do it in a single statement:

```
- foos.each_with_index do |foo, i|
    = link_to(foo.name, foo) + (i < foos.length ? ', ' : '')
```

However, you probably want to extract this code into a helper and write tests.

Comment: Works for me. I like testing against 0 rather than `length`, but I can just flip the concat around.

Comment: A few corrections: (1) Flipping the `+` around doesn't work after all b/c you still get whitespace. (2) It should be `length - 1`, not `length`. (3) You need to run it through `raw`.

Answer (score 3):

HAML comes with a `succeed` method which can be used here:

```
- foos.each do |foo|
  = succeed (foo == foos.last) ? '' : ', ' do
    = link_to foo.name, foo
```

Using string interpolation or an expression, you can conditionally show an empty string or a comma w/ a space.

Comment: I like the idea of setting `succeed`'s argument to the empty string. I think you're doing some extra string work and could just write this though: `= succeed(foo == foos.last ? '' : ', ') do`. Right?

Comment: yeah, you can. it was erroring out on me when first trying, but I probably had some other syntax error. just fired up my rails server and tested. works okay with out interpolation. @PaulAJungwirth